How to map validation errors to use exposed property names in NestJS DTOs?
I'm working on a NestJS project where I need to map validation errors to use the exposed property names defined in my DTOs. Below is my current setup:
DTO:
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class Abcdto {
  @Expose({ name: 'abc_xyz' })
  @IsString()
  readonly abcXyz: string;
}

Controller:
@Post('abc')
abc(@Body() body: Abcdto) {
  return body.abcXyz;
}

When a validation error occurs in my controller, I want the error property to reflect the exposed name (abc_xyz) instead of the original property name (abcXyz). Currently, my validation error response looks like this:
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "abcXyz": "abcXyz must be a string"
    }
  ]
}

But I want it to be:
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "abc_xyz": "abc_xyz must be a string"
    }
  ]
}

I've tried using an exception filter (I18nValidationExceptionFilter) to format the errors, but I'm not sure how to modify it to achieve this mapping. Here is my current exception filter implementation:
import {
  ArgumentsHost,
  Catch,
  ExceptionFilter,
  ValidationError,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import iterate from 'iterare';
import {
  I18nContext,
  I18nValidationError,
  I18nValidationException,
  I18nValidationExceptionFilterDetailedErrorsOption,
  I18nValidationExceptionFilterErrorFormatterOption,
} from 'nestjs-i18n';
import {
  formatI18nErrors,
  mapChildrenToValidationErrors,
} from 'nestjs-i18n/dist/utils';
import { FieldErrorResponse } from '../response/field-error.response';

type I18nValidationExceptionFilterOptions =
  | I18nValidationExceptionFilterDetailedErrorsOption
  | I18nValidationExceptionFilterErrorFormatterOption;

@Catch(I18nValidationException)
export class I18nValidationExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(
    private readonly options: I18nValidationExceptionFilterOptions = {
      detailedErrors: true,
    },
  ) {}
  catch(exception: I18nValidationException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const i18n = I18nContext.current();

    const errors = formatI18nErrors(exception.errors ?? [], i18n.service, {
      lang: i18n.lang,
    });

    const normalizedErrors = this.normalizeValidationErrors(errors);

    switch (host.getType() as string) {
      case 'http':
        const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        const responseBody = this.buildResponseBody(
          host,
          exception,
          normalizedErrors,
        );
        response
          .status(this.options.errorHttpStatusCode || exception.getStatus())
          .send(responseBody);
        break;
      case 'graphql':
        exception.errors = normalizedErrors as I18nValidationError[];
        return exception;
    }
  }

  private isWithErrorFormatter(
    options: I18nValidationExceptionFilterOptions,
  ): options is I18nValidationExceptionFilterErrorFormatterOption {
    return 'errorFormatter' in options;
  }

  protected normalizeValidationErrors(
    validationErrors: ValidationError[],
  ): string[] | I18nValidationError[] | object {
    if (
      this.isWithErrorFormatter(this.options) &&
      !('detailedErrors' in this.options)
    )
      return this.options.errorFormatter(validationErrors);

    if (
      !this.isWithErrorFormatter(this.options) &&
      !this.options.detailedErrors
    )
      return this.flattenValidationErrors(validationErrors);

    return validationErrors;
  }

  protected flattenValidationErrors(
    validationErrors: ValidationError[],
  ): string[] {
    return iterate(validationErrors)
      .map((error) => mapChildrenToValidationErrors(error))
      .flatten()
      .filter((item) => !!item.constraints)
      .map((item) => Object.values(item.constraints))
      .flatten()
      .toArray();
  }

  protected buildResponseBody(
    host: ArgumentsHost,
    exc: I18nValidationException,
    errors: string[] | I18nValidationError[] | object,
  ) {
    if ('responseBodyFormatter' in this.options) {
      return this.options.responseBodyFormatter(host, exc, errors);
    } else {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: exc.getResponse() as string,
        errors: (errors as I18nValidationError[]).map((error) => {
          return {
            [error.property]: Object.values(error.constraints).pop(),
          };
        }),
      } satisfies FieldErrorResponse;
    }
  }
}

I want the error property to be abc_xyz instead of abcXyz. How can I achieve this in my current setup?
